# kadane algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I have the following implementation of Kadane's algorithm in java. It is basically to find the maximum sum of contiguous subarray.

```
String[] numbers = string.split(",");
                int max_so_far = 0;
                int max_ending_here = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1;i++){
                     max_ending_here = max_ending_here + Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
                     if (max_ending_here < 0)
                         max_ending_here = 0;
                     if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
                          max_so_far = max_ending_here;
                }
                System.out.println(max_so_far);
```

However this doesn't work if there is a combination of a negative and positive number in an array, for example the following:

```
2,3,-2,-1,10
```

Which should return a 12 as a maximum. As of now it returns 5

Comment: What is the question here?  Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: what value does it give at the moment?

Comment: Or i<=numbers.length-1 would have made better understand about the length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You algorithm implementation looks ok, but your loop conditional `i < numbers.length-1` does not: it stops just 1 short of the end of the array. `i < numbers.length` should do it :-)

Comment: yes, that is such a stupid mistake.. thanks! it happens once in a while

Comment: This is why for each loop is so great. You avoid such gotchas.

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
    String string = "2,3,-2,-1,10";
    String[] numbers = string.split(",");
    int max_so_far = 0;
    int max_ending_here = 0;
    for (String num : numbers) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(num);
        max_ending_here = Math.max(0, max_ending_here + x);
        max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
    }
    System.out.println(max_so_far);
```

Comment: This fails if all the elements in the array are negative.  you probably need to initialize your variables to Integer.MIN_VALUE or to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the above answer by Michał Šrajer:

Line #7: max_ending_here = Math.max(0, max_ending_here + x);

should be:

max_ending_here = Math.max(x, max_ending_here + x);

...according to the Kadane algorithm as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm)

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. It is important to note that if all the numbers in the input array are -ve then the accepted solution will not give the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but if someone needs it in the future.

```
public static void kadaneAlgo(int[][] array)
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
            int max_value_index_i = numberOrSum(array[i], past);
            if(max_value_index_i > sum){
                sum = max_value_index_i;
            }
            past = max_value_index_i;

        }
        System.out.println("Max sum from a contiguous sub array is : " + sum);
    }

    public static int numberOrSum(int number, int past){
        return Math.max(number, number+past);
    }
```