# determine the largest sum of contiguous integers in a list java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a problem on codeeval.com - http://codeeval.com/open_challenges/17/. 
"Write a program to determine the largest sum of contiguous integers in a list".

Input is a text file containing comma separated list of integers, one per line e.g.

-10, 2, 3, -2, 0, 5, -15

2,3,-2,-1,10

That input should produce 8 for the first line and 12 for the second. My answer is below, but I cannot see how to get 12 for the second line, so my question is mainly what am I missing, am I misinterpreting what's being asked for? (I get 13 for the answer)

N.B. - I live in Ireland so this is purely for my own experience, you won't be helping me with a job application! Also, I went through every similar question on here and couldn't find anything relevant.

If my interpretation of the question is incorrect, all I need is a point in the right direction, not necessarily code. (As in, can someone point out how the second line evaluates to 12 and not 13)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class largest_sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        FileReader input = new FileReader(args[0]);
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
        String line;

        line = bufRead.readLine();

        while(line != null) { 
            addInts(line);
            line = bufRead.readLine();
        }
        bufRead.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void addInts(String line) {
        String[] numbers = line.split(",");
        Integer largest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
        Integer secondLargest = 0;
        for(String s : numbers) {
            Integer converted = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
            if(converted > largest) {

                secondLargest =  largest;
                largest = converted;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largest + secondLargest);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I live in Ireland so this is purely for my own experience, you won't be helping me with a job application" - what does living in Ireland have to do with it?

Comment: Because it's a challenge for a job for people who can work in the US...
I'm doing it just for experience. Not the job application.

Comment: Your mistake is that you are adding the two biggest numbers from the sequence. But they are not necessarily consecutive! In the considered case, the sequence `3, 10` is not a solution to the problem, however it's chosen by your algorithm. For the description of how the problem should be solved, see @mtsvetkov's answer.

Comment: You code should declare that it throws `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @JonSkeet - I could be politically incorrect and point out that it is the sort of thing that an Irishman would say :-)

Comment: "I live in Ireland so ... you won't be helping me with a job application!" No jobs in Ireland? :(

Comment: Bwhahaha, no plenty of jobs for a programmer, just you need a Visa for US work. :P

Comment: @Saf There are jobs in London for which you don't need a vista. ;)

Comment: @Peter, that's where I'm headed when I graduate, not too long to go :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Edit: As @Paolo and @Vlad pointed out - you're not getting the correct result because you are adding the largest two numbers, as opposed to looking for a sequence. Kadane's algorithm finds the largest sum of a sequence by first finding the largest sum ending at each position in your data set.

Comment: A quick Google on that algorithm solved the problem instantly. Now I just need to make sure I understand it, very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking to find the greatest sum of **contiguous** integers.  Your program is picking the largest and second largest and adding them together, not the same thing.

In the first line, the greatest sum is acheived by taking the subseqence:

```
2, 3, -2, 0, 5
```

which sums to 8 (the fact that the 2 and -2 cancel out leaving you with effectively the largest + second largest numbers is a red herring).

In the second line the greatest sum is acheived by the taking the whole sequence:

```
2 + 3 + -2 + -1 + 10
```

which sums to 12.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, if I could let two questions be the answer I would! Gave it +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the your code with below algorithm. Basically If I have understood `correctly it is like find valid integer on the right side then move to left side and find valid integer there then get the sum.`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    addInts("-10,2,3,-2,0,5,-15");
    addInts("2,3,-2,-1,10");
}

public static void addInts(String line) {
    String[] numbers = line.split(",");
    // First convert Strings to integer array

    int[] ints = new int[numbers.length];
    int count = 0;

    for (String number : numbers) {
        ints[count++] = Integer.parseInt(number);
    }

    // now find first valid and last valid

    int firstValidIndex = -1;
    int lastValidIndex = -1;
    for (count = 0;;) {
        if (ints[count] < 0 && firstValidIndex == -1) {
            count++;
            continue;
        } else {
            if (firstValidIndex == -1) {
                firstValidIndex = count;
                //Swap the loop here now we have to find backwards              
                count = ints.length - 1;
            } else {
                if (ints[count] < 0) {
                    count--;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    lastValidIndex = count;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    // Calculate the sum now
    int sum = 0;
    for (count = firstValidIndex; count <= lastValidIndex; count++) {
        sum = sum + ints[count];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Output

```
8
12
```

Comment: No, I think it's just a happy coincidence that those numbers worked out, I think they went out of their way to throw red herrings in the input & expected answer. The correct answer involves applying Kadane's algorithm - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233042/kadane-algorithm-in-java.
Mind you, I didn't understand the question properly either, hence the posting here!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.salpe.scjp.algo;

public class Algo1 {

    private static int[] test = new int[] { -10, 2, 3, -2, 0, 5, -15 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int highestSum = test[0];

        int higheststart = 0;
        int highestend = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    System.out.print("[ " + i + ", " + j );
                    System.out.print(" = "+findSum(i, j) +"]");

                    if(highestSum <  findSum(i, j)){
                        highestSum =  findSum(i, j);
                        higheststart = i;
                        highestend = j;
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println("");

        }

        System.out.println("Highest Sum " +highestSum);
        toString(higheststart, highestend);

    }

    public static int  findSum(int i, int j) {

        int sum =0;

        for (int j2 = i; j2 <= j; j2++) {

            sum = sum +test[j2];

        }

        return sum;
    }


    public static int  toString(int i, int j) {

        int sum =0;

        for (int j2 = i; j2 <= j; j2++) {

            System.out.print(" ,"+test[j2]);

        }

        return sum;
    }

}


----------

[ 0, 1 = -8][ 0, 2 = -5][ 0, 3 = -7][ 0, 4 = -7][ 0, 5 = -2][ 0, 6 = -17]
[ 1, 0 = 0][ 1, 2 = 5][ 1, 3 = 3][ 1, 4 = 3][ 1, 5 = 8][ 1, 6 = -7]
[ 2, 0 = 0][ 2, 1 = 0][ 2, 3 = 1][ 2, 4 = 1][ 2, 5 = 6][ 2, 6 = -9]
[ 3, 0 = 0][ 3, 1 = 0][ 3, 2 = 0][ 3, 4 = -2][ 3, 5 = 3][ 3, 6 = -12]
[ 4, 0 = 0][ 4, 1 = 0][ 4, 2 = 0][ 4, 3 = 0][ 4, 5 = 5][ 4, 6 = -10]
[ 5, 0 = 0][ 5, 1 = 0][ 5, 2 = 0][ 5, 3 = 0][ 5, 4 = 0][ 5, 6 = -10]
[ 6, 0 = 0][ 6, 1 = 0][ 6, 2 = 0][ 6, 3 = 0][ 6, 4 = 0][ 6, 5 = 0]
Highest Sum 8
 ,2 ,3 ,-2 ,0 ,5
```